DEC's "decimal ASCII"?
I'm reading some older FOCAL documents and see references to things like...
SETS X TO THE DECIMAL ASCII CODE OF THE INPUT CHARACTER

A bit later there is a table of these codes, and unless I am not looking hard enough, this appears to simply be the ASCII code + 128.
Storing these codes in 12-bit memory should be possible without the high bit (which in this case isn't the high bit), and removing it would not allow packing, so...
Does anyone know why they used this format?

It seems you're talking about the FIN/FOUT character functions added with FOCAL-71.

Yes, They handle characters (roughly *1) as ASCII+128.
No, they do not relate to any decimal (BCD) functionality.
They are simply all about handling single characters as numeric value.
They are not related to "Alphanumeric Numbers"

It helps to remember that FOCAL started out as purely numeric language. Strings (and thus characters) were only available as constants for output purpose. FOCAL-71 added FIN/FOUT for very minimal character handling (*2).

FIN would read a single character form input and returning it's character code as numeric value (*3) - kinda like INKEY in some BASIC - according to the mentioned table.
FOUT could be used to output any character by using that code - which equals (*1) to basic ASCII+128.

With those functions very basic character handling could be done - like handling special input strings - like for non decimal currency - and/or generating text for such output.

Please also note Dave's answer mentioning the underlaying technical reason as the 7 bit TTY character being filled with an 8th Mark bit.

*1 - No lower case IIRC.
*2 - Well, there was a somewhat odd way to enter characters: When an input response to ASK didn't start with a numeral, the character, if in range A..Z), was assinged as numeric value with A=1 to Z=26.
*3 - After all, there were only numeric variables to hold whatever is to be delivered :)

That's what the hardware uses.

To convert the ASCII code to Teletype code, add 200 octal (ASCII +
2008 = Teletype).

See Chapter 2 in the 1966 PDP-8 Users Handbook.
The Teletype Model 33 Technical Manual shows this, in section 7.1. The high bit (bit 8 in Teletype numbering) is always set. This is confirmed on page 7-2:

However, at the present it utilizes only the first seven intelligence
units, the eighth always being transmitted as marking.

It appears to have been conventional for PDP-8 software to use Teletype code rather than plain ASCII.  For another example, see Appendix A (character codes) in the OS8 system manual -- all 8-bit codes are 2008 or greater.

Years later it was common (still is, actually) to configure a serial port to handle odd/even/mark/space parity, even back in PDP-8 days I think it would have made sense to handle this in output circuitry rather than set it in application software. Then if you have a different model of terminal that wants something different you don't have to change your software.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact What "different model of terminal" would you use? PDP-8 was extremely minimalist, nothing about it was merely "nice to have".

@JohnDoty I honestly don't know. The first terminal I recall using was a TTY 33...and that was around 1977 or so (on a computer a generation beyond the PDP-8), and the history of ASCII (at least according to Wikipedia) supports the 33 as being the main ASCII terminal for quite a while. But it seems odd to me that the system would be set up specifically for mark in software and not just force it in hardware.

It's been the same with any early machine in each generation, it was all about getting anything to be done. Abstraction, portability or whatsoever were not a concern. In fact, one hardly even know that it could be any different a being 192 seemed normal and the way it had to be :)) No matter if PDP-8 or Apple II.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - the Teletype manual I quoted said that the model 33 (as it was then) does set the 200 bit. It wasn't an option.  With modern eyes, it would make sense to isolate programs from device-specific details, but those were different times. (On the KDF9, we had 3 different character codes: terminal, printer, and file system - and at the assembly-code level at least, you needed to know this).

Don't forget - there wasn't necessarily an operating system. FOCAL ran on the bare metal.  A read from the TTY (KRB instruction) apparently returned the code with the 200 bit set.   FOCAL could have cleared it, but why would it?  Every PDP-8 document says 'A' is 301 and not 101 octal.

Didn't the paper tape reader and punch use all 8 bits?

@JohnDoty - good question.  I see nothing in the Teletype manual, or in the PDP-8 manuals I examined.  Presumably if you SAVE from FOCAL, the high bit is always set. But if punched, that would needlessly weaken the tape... so I don't know.

FWIW, by 1974 the model 33 supported a (wired) customer option to select bit 8 = even parity, always mark, always space.

"The high bit (bit 8 in Teletype numbering) is always set" - ahh, this explains it!

Didn't 0200 set indicate a binary value on punched tape?
